# Find difference (delta) between all columns over multiple indexes using Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Takes the following for example:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), "product": "product_1", "price": 90, "quantity": 100, "code": "code-1.1"},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), "product": "product_2", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-2.1"},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), "product": "product_3", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-3.1"},

    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), "product": "product_1", "price": 90, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-1.1"},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), "product": "product_2", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-2.1"},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), "product": "product_3", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-3.1"},

    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), "product": "product_1", "price": 90, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-1.1"},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), "product": "product_2", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-2.2"},

    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), "product": "product_1", "price": 80, "quantity": 70, "code": "code-1.1"},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), "product": "product_2", "price": 70, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-2.2"},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), "product": "product_3", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-3.1"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(["date", "product"])
```

Want I want to be able to do is produce a difference/delta on each none-index column and only output the changed columns and don't output days where nothing has changed, but also identify when days have been missed and then output the all the columns for that date/product the following day.

An example output would be:

```
{"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), "product": "product_1", "price": 90, "quantity": 100, "code": "code-1.1"},
{"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), "product": "product_2", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-2.1"},
{"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), "product": "product_3", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-3.1"},
{"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), "product": "product_1", "price": None, "quantity": 80, "code": None},
{"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), "product": "product_2", "price": None, "quantity": None, "code": "code-2.2"},
{"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), "product": "product_1", "price": 80, "quantity": 70, "code": None},
{"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), "product": "product_2", "price": 70, "quantity": None, "code": None},
{"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), "product": "product_3", "price": 80, "quantity": 80, "code": "code-3.1"},
```

To clarify the above:

For `product_1`: Date 2020-01-03 is missing due to nothing has changed in the columns (price, quantity) - whereas for the date 2020-01-02, the price is `None` due to it not changing.

For `product_2`: Date 2020-01-01 is present due to being the first datapoint, the code changes on 2020-01-03, and the price is updated on the 2020-01-04.

For `product_3`: Date 2020-01-01 is present due to being the first datapoint, date 2020-01-04 is present due to the previous date (2020-01-03) we didn't have any data for that day.

I have tried iterating on the dataframe but fear that this will be slow scaling up. I feel something like `pct_change` would work, but from reading this doesn't work on multi-indexes.

Also as answers have reflected diff would work on `int` columns, however I ideally need this to work on also `str` columns as well.

Comment: You could use `df['price']-df['price'].shift(-1)` for example to get the difference in price from one day to the next, then use [nonzero](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.nonzero.html) to get indices where the columns aren't zero for dropping or masking

Comment: @G.Anderson but I want to do this over multiple columns (price and quantity) and in the future this would be over many more columns.

Answer (score 1):

For a single product

```py
diffs = df.diff()
df[diffs == 0] = None
df[~(diffs == 0).all(axis=1)]
```

```
        price   quantity
date    product     
2020-01-01  product_1   90.0    100.0
2020-01-02  product_1   NaN     80.0
2020-01-04  product_1   80.0    70.0
```

For multiple products

```py
def show_diffs(df):
    diffs = df.diff()
    df[diffs == 0] = None
    return df[~(diffs == 0).all(axis=1)]

df.groupby('product').apply(show_diffs).sort_values('date')
```

```
                                    price   quantity
product     date        product     
product_1   2020-01-01  product_1   90.0    100.0
product_2   2020-01-01  product_2   80.0    80.0
product_1   2020-01-02  product_1   NaN     80.0
            2020-01-04  product_1   80.0    70.0
product_2   2020-01-04  product_2   70.0    NaN
```

Comment: This works if there's only one product, how would this work when there's multiple products?

Comment: It depends on how does your dataframe stores the product information. If you have 'product_1', 'product_2', etc. in the same column, then probably you can structure them with `groupby` and pass the above steps as a function.

Comment: @MarcusChaplais added solution with groupby

Comment: Looks good! How would this work with if I added a column that only dealt with strings however? For example a `product_code` which could potentially change over time and I would want to have a diff for that as well? As my understand `.diff()` only deals with numbers.

Comment: Perhaps create `int` column from it and use that? `df['product_code'] = df.index.get_level_values('product').str[-1].astype(int)`.

Comment: What if we had multiple str columns. Ideally I don't want to hard code an `astype` for each of these columns.